# what is wrong with this create table syntax

Tags: mysql, create-table

Here is my create table and this is the error I am getting

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `teamfocus_dbo`.`sysdiagrams`;
CREATE TABLE `teamfocus_dbo`.`sysdiagrams` (
    `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `principal_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `diagram_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` INT(10) NULL,
  `definition` VARBINARY(-1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`diagram_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UK_principal_name` (`principal_id`, `name`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

**ERROR**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`diagram_id`),
 UNIQUE INDEX `UK_principal_name` (`pri' at line 6
```

I even tried to take out the UNIQUE line and still erroring...any ideas

Comment: `-1` is valid size for `VARBINARY`?

Comment: I changed it to 1 and the query ran...interesting ...not sure where -1 came from. ALthough this was an SQL db prior to moving over to mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-1` isn't a valid length for `VARBINARY` for most databases:

SQL Server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

> varbinary [ ( n | max) ]
>
> Variable-length binary data. n can be a value
>   from 1 through 8,000.

MySQL:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html

Refers to `VARCHAR` which provides the following limits:

> The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL
>   5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html